# Fitting glm without explicit declaration of each covariate

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm

When I fit a linear model with many predictor variables, I can avoid writing all of them by using `.` as follows:

```
model = lm(target_deathrate~., data = full_data)
```

But for models with higher complexity, I cannot make this work:

```
x = glm(target_deathrate~poly(., i),data = full_data)
```

In these cases I have to write all variables.

How to avoid writing all variable names and include all variables in my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3588961/674487) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252958/674487).

The main idea is to create the formula from a string with `as.formula`:

```
xnam <- paste("x", 1:25, sep="")
fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+")))
```